# When Method Not Allowed exception will raise

Tags: powershell, kql

I have a code to fetch the records from kusto DB using powershell script. But I am getting "(405) Method Not Allowed." while executing rest API

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount

$ClusterUri = "kql url"
$DatabaseName = "database Name"

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl $ClusterUri).Token

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$kqlQuery = @"
TableName
"@

# Build the request body in JSON format
$requestBody = @{
    csl = $kqlQuery
    "query" = "TableName"
} | ConvertTo-Json

uri = "https://$ClusterUri/databases/$DatabaseName/query"
try{
$queryResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $requestBody
"Success"
$queryResult
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $responseContent = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($responseContent)
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    Write-Host "Error Message: $errorMessage"
    Write-Host "Response Body: $responseBody"
}
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that suggested `/databases/<dbName>/query` was the correct endpoint? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/) is sounds like you need to request `/v2/rest/query` instead...

Comment: Can you guide me to compose the entire uri, I am sure about clusteruri and database name